# Programming a Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, neural-network

In order to get some understanding of machine learning (i'm super new to this) I'm programming a neural network and try to train a sinefunction with it. The set-up is as follows:

- Backpropagation algorithm with stochastic gradient descent
- 1 input (x between [0,2*pi], sine function as target) plus optionally
  a biasinput. The sine function is scaled to [0,1]
- a variable no. of hidden layers with a variable no. of hidden units
- sigmoid activation functions
- weights initialized randomly between -0.05 and 0.05

I expected a network with for example 4 hidden layers and 25 hidden units in each hidden layer to be deep enough to predict a sine, but instead the 'learned' output sticks to roughly the average of the scaled sinefunction (i.e 0.5).

I was wondering if somebody has had a similar experience and how it was fixed, or whether I am overlooking/misunderstanding something in my code. In this image ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6glp.png ) I have illustrated the setup and some nomenclature of my code shown below.

Thank you for your time and help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class neural(object):

def __init__(self,samples,n_in,n_hidden,n_hlayers,eta,bias):
    self.samples = samples
    self.n_in = n_in
    self.n_out = n_in
    self.n_hidden = n_hidden
    self.n_hlayers = n_hlayers
    self.eta = eta
    self.bias = bias

    # Prepare data with range [0,1)
    if self.bias is True:
        x = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(self.samples,self.n_in)
        t = (np.sin(x)+1)/2

        x = np.append(x,np.ones([self.samples,1]),axis=1)
        self.n_in += 1
    else:
        x = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(self.samples,self.n_in)          
        t = (np.sin(x)+1)/2

    # Partitioning
    self.x_train = x[0:self.samples/2]
    self.t_train = t[0:self.samples/2]
    self.x_test = x[self.samples/2:]
    self.t_test = t[self.samples/2:]

    # Create weight matrices
    self.get_weights()


def get_weights(self):
    # Initialize weights with values [-b,+b)
    a = 0.1
    b = 0.05

    # Weigths from input layer to 1st hidden layer
    self.w_ih = a*np.random.rand(self.n_hidden, self.n_in)-b

    # Weigths between hidden layers
    if self.n_hlayers > 1:
        self.w_hh = np.zeros([self.n_hidden,self.n_hidden,self.n_hlayers-1])
        for i in range(0,self.n_hlayers-1):
            self.w_hh[:,:,i] = a*np.random.rand(self.n_hidden, self.n_hidden)-b

    # Weigths from last hidden layer to output layer
    self.w_ho = a*np.random.rand(self.n_out,self.n_hidden)-b   


def train(self,xi,ti): 
    # 1. Feedforward 
    # Output z from the first hidden layer (right next to the input layer)
    z = np.zeros([self.n_hidden,1,self.n_hlayers])
    z[:,:,0] = fsigmoid(np.dot(self.w_ih,xi))

    # Output from other hidden layers
    if self.n_hlayers > 1:          
        for i in range(0,self.n_hlayers-1):
            z[:,:,i+1] = fsigmoid(np.dot(self.w_hh[:,:,i],z[:,:,i]))

    # Output from output layer        
    o = fsigmoid(np.dot(self.w_ho,z[:,:,-1])) 

    # 2. Backpropagation 
    delta_o = o*(np.ones([self.n_out,1])-o)*(ti-o)
    delta_who = self.eta*np.dot(delta_o,z[:,:,-1].T)

    if self.n_hlayers > 1:
        # Preallocate 3D array to contain all layers
        delta_h = np.zeros([self.n_hidden,1,self.n_hlayers])
        delta_whh = np.zeros([self.n_hidden,self.n_hidden,self.n_hlayers-1])

        # Backpropagation from outer layer to first hidden layer
        delta_h[:,:,-1] = z[:,:,-1]*(1-z[:,:,-1])*np.dot(self.w_ho.T,delta_o)
        delta_whh[:,:,-1] = self.eta*np.dot(delta_h[:,:,-1],z[:,:,-2].T)

        # Backpropagation between other hidden layers (walking from right 
        # to left in the network)
        for i in range(-2,-1*self.n_hlayers,-1):
            delta_h[:,:,i] = z[:,:,i]*(1-z[:,:,i])*np.dot(self.w_hh[:,:,i+1].T,delta_h[:,:,i+1])
            delta_whh[:,:,i] = self.eta*np.dot(delta_h[:,:,i],z[:,:,i-1].T) 

    # To the input layer
    if self.n_hlayers > 1:
        i = -1*self.n_hlayers
        delta_h[:,:,i] = z[:,:,i]*(1-z[:,:,i])*np.dot(self.w_hh[:,:,i+1].T,delta_h[:,:,i+1])
        delta_wih = self.eta*np.dot(delta_h[:,:,i],xi.T) 
    else:
       delta_h = z[:,:,-1]*(1-z[:,:,-1])*np.dot(delta_who.T,delta_o)
       delta_wih = self.eta*np.dot(delta_h,xi.T)           

    # 3. Update weights
    self.w_ho += delta_who
    self.w_ih += delta_wih
    if self.n_hlayers > 1:
        self.w_hh += delta_whh

    return o


def fsigmoid(y):
    sigma = 1/(1+np.exp(-y))
    return sigma


def relu(y):
    z = (abs(y)+y)/2
    return z


if __name__ == '__main__':

    network = neural(samples=20000,n_in=1,n_hidden=25,n_hlayers=4,eta=0.01,bias=False)

    # For each training example pair <x(i),t(i)>
    err = []
    out = []
    for i in range(0,network.samples/2):
        print 'Iteration',i+1
        xi = network.x_train[i].reshape([network.n_in,1])
        ti = network.t_train[i].reshape([network.n_out,1])
        output = network.train(xi,ti)

        # Error of training set
        RMSerr = np.sqrt(np.sum((output-ti)**2)/network.n_out)
        err.append(RMSerr)

        # To do: add error of validationset set (prevent overfitting)

        # Save trained output
        out.append(output[0])

    plt.close('all') 
    plt.plot(network.x_train,out,'.')
    plt.hold(True)
    plt.plot(network.x_train,network.t_train,'x')
```